# how can i use " componentDidMount" to "fetch" and pass a query string

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have created a gif search engine , where by typing  on the search field it shows "gifs" related to that text, i have used 'superagent 'to handle the api and I have used this code

```
  onSearchChange = (event) => {
    const url = `http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${event.target.value.replace(/\s/g, '+')}&limit=10&api_key=${API_KEY}`;
      request.get(url, (err, res) => {
        this.setState({ gifs: res.body.data })
      });
  }
```

Now my question is how can i use " componentDidMount" with "fetch" to change that "onSearchChange"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to call api every time `search` field updates. Appropriate lifecycle method to make api call in this case would be `componentDidUpdate`. `componentDidMount` will only be called once your component is mounted.

1.On change of `search` field, update `state` to reflect current `search` field.
   e.g. `this.setState({ search: currentValue })`

2.Once state is updated, `componentDidUpdate` will be called. Now, you can make api call in this method.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
      if (prevState.search !== this.state.search) { // or compare with `prevState`
        this.onSearchChange(this.state.search);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Mukesh, I did like this:

componentDidMount() {
    fetch(API_URL + DEFAULT_QUERY + API_KEY)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(items => {
        this.setState({ gifs: items.data})});
  }

  onSearchChange = (event) => {
    fetch(API_URL + event.target.value + API_KEY)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(items => {
        this.setState({ gifs: items.data})});
  }

initially i am displayng sm default results & after typing on the the searchbar the nw results r showing but whn i clr the texts frm  searchbar its nt showing the default gifs

Comment: In that case, you need to store default gifs in another state variable so that `onSearchChange` does not overrides your `default gifs`. So, you need to keep 2 variables in state... one for default gifs and another for gifs fetched from onSearchChange. Once you have that, you can do `value={this.state.fetchedGifs || this.state.defaultGifs}` in your render component.

Comment: @SayanMukherjee Did above comment helped you?

Comment: sorry for replying late.. just tried and it worked...thank you so much Mukesh.

Comment: I have another problem ..created a new question .. I am trying to add redux to my react app.. but I am facing issues on how to pass the value to the fetched url https://stackoverflow.com/q/58084313/3497043?sem=2