# React-redux passing a value to url for gif search

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have created this react app https://ssayanm.github.io/giphy-redux/ , used redux, now I want to change the result gif's based on the search field, currently, I cannot pass the value to my query string via api.

I have logger added, I can see that the payload is showing the "Search box" input value but how to pass that value.

Github repo: https://github.com/ssayanm/giphy-redux

Thank you

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Questions need to stand on their own. Redux doesn't care (much) what you pass as data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update function `setSearchField`:

```
export const setSearchField = text => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: REQUEST_GIFS_PENDING });
  fetch(API_URL + text + API_KEY + LIMIT)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(items =>
      dispatch({ type: REQUEST_GIFS_SUCCESS, payload: items.data })
    )
    //.fetch(API_URL + dispatch. + API_KEY + LIMIT)
    .catch(error => dispatch({ type: REQUEST_GIFS_FAILED, payload: error }));
};
```

See live example:

[image: Edit giphysearch]

Comment: thank you, it worked .. now initially the default gifs are loading and after adding some text on the search box , its showing the search results but when the search box is empty its not showing any gifs, how can i show the default gifs again like when it is initially loading .. I have created a separate component and also I have used the "requestgif" action to fetch default query.. what am i doing wrong.. I have pushed the latest files on github

Comment: how do i call the componentdidmount once again when the search bar is empty

Comment: Hi.. I have fixed the issue ..now its working .. https://ssayanm.github.io/giphy-redux/ .. thank you for your help.. how can i connect with you .. I have checked your website.. its so cool .. ;-)